# Rails error - app not picking up validations and/or error prevention code block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I'm building an events app which uses simple form in views for the user to create an event. I'm trying to implement validations so that certain details must be present. When I've tested this - by deliberately missing out sections of the form - I've run into a whole host of issues/bugs/errors which get thrown up.The only way to reset back to normal is for me to delete the 'toxic' event via the console.

It's as though the validations and the error code block in views are having no effect, the event is still being created and assigned an id and the code is just breaking, creating a bug, when I deliberately omit sections of the form.

No idea why this would be happening. This is my relevant code -

EventsController.rb

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_event, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy,]
# the before_actions will take care of finding the correct event for us
# this ties in with the private method below
before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
# this ensures only users who are signed in can alter an event



def new
    @event = current_user.events.build
    # this now builds out from a user once devise gem is added
    # after initially having an argument of Event.new
    # this assigns events to users
end

def create
    @event = current_user.events.build(event_params)
    # as above this now assigns events to users
    # rather than Event.new

    if @event.save
        redirect_to @event, notice: "Congratulations, you have successfully created a new event."
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

private

def event_params
    params.require(:event).permit(:title, :location, :date, :time, :description, :number_of_spaces, :is_free, :price, :organised_by, :url, :image, :category_id)
    # category_id added at the end to ensure this is assigned to each new event created
end

def find_event
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
end







end
```

This is my form partial which has an error code block - this initially threw up an error stating that 0 arguments were being passed when expecting 2.

_form.events.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(@event) do |f| %>
<% if @event.errors.any? %>
    <h2><%= pluralize(@event.errors.count, "error") %> prevented this Event from saving:</h2>
    <ul>
        <% @event.errors.full_message.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
<% end %>

<%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, {prompt: "Choose a category"} %>
<!-- The above code loop assigns a category_id to each event -->

<%= f.input :image, as: :file, label: 'Image' %>
<%= f.input :title, label: 'Event Title' %>
<label>Location</label><%= f.text_field :location, id: 'geocomplete' %></br>
<label>Date</label><%= f.text_field :date, label: 'Date', id: 'datepicker' %>
<%= f.input :time, label: 'Time' %>
<%= f.input :description, label: 'Description' %>
<label>Number of spaces available</label><%= f.text_field :number_of_spaces, label: 'Number of spaces' %>
<%= f.input :is_free, label: 'Tick box if Event is free of charge' %>
<!--f.input :currency, :collection => [['£GBP - British Pounds',1],['$USD - US Dollars',2],['€EUR - Euros',3]] -->
<%= f.input :price, label: 'Cost per person (leave blank if free of charge)' %>
<%= f.input :organised_by, label: 'Organised by' %>
<%= f.input :url, label: "Link to Organiser site" %>

<%= f.button :submit, label: 'Submit' %>

<% end %>
```

Event model with validations. The errors occur whether validations are included or not (I've taken them out and tried with same results).

Event.rb

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :category
belongs_to :user
has_many :bookings
has_many :comments


has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "300x300>" }
validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

validates_associated :category
validates :title, :description, :location, :date, :time, :number_of_spaces, :price_pennies, presence: true


monetize :price_pennies
# required for money-rails gem to function

end
```

The error messages seem to bounce all over the place from 'ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken' to 'undefined method' on a line of code in my show page -

```
<p><%= @event.date.strftime('%A, %d %b %Y') %></p>
```

when I attempt to leave the date field empty.

Comment: Can you show some error messages and leave out code that is not relevant to the question? (like controller show/index/edit/update/destroy).

About the authenticity token: is it present in the HTML when you submit the form. Is it submitted to the controller?

Comment: How do I show the error codes on here? I've fixed the error by deleting the event in the console but know it will happen again. The error about the authenticity token related to the create action in the events controller. I'll update my answer re your comments about relevant code.

Comment: The first error I get is this -

Comment: ArgumentError - in Events#create, wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2) and it highlights this line in my code for the form partial -     <% @event.errors.full_message.each do |message| %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here in your view is your problem:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@event) do |f| %>
<% if @event.errors.any? %>
    <h2><%= pluralize(@event.errors.count, "error") %> prevented this Event from saving:</h2>
    <ul>
        <% @event.errors.full_message.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
<% end %>
```

specifically, this part:

```
<% @event.errors.full_message.each do |message| %>
```

Zooming in:

```
@event.errors.full_message
```

You forgot an "s" at the end of the method name, it should be:

```
@event.errors.full_messages
```

The `full_message` method takes 2 arguments and is used to return a single full error message for a given attribute. This typo was giving you the error.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-full_message

Comment: Many thanks - I spotted this also (see my comments above) but many thanks for the detailed answer which I've marked correct. Feel free to answer any of my other questions in such detail, I'm learning all the time:)

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead I highly recommend posting each problem and questions in its own stackoverflow question. This makes it easier for us to answer and is overall better for the community should someone be searching for a solution to the same problem(s).

Comment: That's what I've done. is there a way on here to ask specific users the question your asking? There's a couple fo questions I've put on here where I've had no response and I'm still trying to figure out the solution.